# метод массива выявляющий минимальное число кроме отрицательных чисел js

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вывести минимальное, не отрицательное число массива. В данном случае цифру 1.

Плюсом будет еще и вывести индекс под которым находятся минимальные значения.

При этом индекс массива должен начинаться не с "0" а с "1".
Короче вывести минимальное число `${number}, под ${index}`.

```
const arr = [8, 1, 1, 3, 2, -1, 5]
```

Как в этом случае лучше поступить?

Было бы не плохо, чтобы этот код был еще и лаконичным.

Comment: Как пробовали вы решить эту задачу и с чем возникли сложности?

Comment: @SwaD Я пробовал решать разными способами. Через forEach с использование if else через reduce. Но мне не хватает практики в построении логической конструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов. Вернет первый минимальный элемент

```js
const arr = [8, -2, 1, 1, 3, 2, -1, 5];

function minNum(data) {
  let min = Infinity;
  let idx = -1;
  data.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item > 0 && min > item) {
      min = item;
      idx = index;
    }
  })
  return [min, idx + 1];
}

const minimum = minNum(arr);
console.log(`${minimum[0]}, под ${minimum[1]}`)
```

Такой же, но немного оптимизированный вариант. Как только будет найден минимальный номер(1 в нашем случае), цикл прекратит работу и вернет результат.

```js
const arr = [8, -2, 1, 1, 3, 2, -1, 5];

function minFor(data) {
  let min = Infinity;
  let idx = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > 0 && min > data[i]) {
      min = data[i];
      idx = i;
      if (min === 1) return [min, idx + 1];
    }
  }
}

const minimum3 = minFor(arr);
console.log(`${minimum3[0]}, под ${minimum3[1]}`)
```

Comment: Заоптимизировали случай, когда минимальный неотрицательный элемент массива больше единицы. P.S. Вроде бы ноль тоже считается неотрицательным числом.

Comment: @wololo Мне показалось что именно про 1 речь. не отрицательный, но и не ноль. Если не так, думаю автор сможет сам поправить. В любом случае, если "самого" минимального нет в массиве, то оба варианта пробегуться по всему массиву...

Comment: @SwaD @ksa Спасибо. Было интересно посмотреть разные варианты. Во всех трех вариантах применяется Infinity это свойство для меня новое и я еще не до конца понимаю как с ним работать. Поэтому мне было сложновато понять логику. 
И еще один момент, который я в изначальном сообщении не уточнил, Нужно было вывести 2 индекса с минимальным числом. То есть `минимальное число 1 под 2, 3`

Comment: @user20389696 Тогда это уже совершенно другая задача. Попробуйте сами реализовать с учетом полученных знанний. Не получится, создайте новый вопрос, указав задачу, которую решаете, ваши попытки и где возникли сложности

Comment: `minFor([2])` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Было бы не плохо, чтобы этот код был еще и лаконичным.

Ну не знаю... Достаточно лаконично?

```js
const arr = [8, 1, 1, 3, 2, -1, 5]

const o = arr.reduce((o, v, i) => v < 0? o: v < o.v? {v, i: ++i}: o, {v: Infinity, i: null}) 
const txt = `${o.v}, под ${o.i}`
console.log(txt)
```